# FFmpeg produces empty file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have problems with ffmpeg on OSX Lion. I am trying to convert the mpeg file and the output is always a file of size 400kb or so..

The command is:

```
 ffmpeg -i out_poem_big.mpg -s 1280x720 -vpre medium outvideo.mp4
```

Here is the log:

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 21 2012 21:57:04 with gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
  configuration: --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.6.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --disable-indev=jack --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaad
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (60000/1001) -> 29.97 (60000/2002)
Input #0, mpeg, from 'out_poem_big.mpg':
  Duration: 00:08:35.61, start: 1.000000, bitrate: 14823 kb/s
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 104857 kb/s, 28.90 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
File 'outvideo.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7ca033600]using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7ca033600]using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7ca033600]profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7ca033600]264 - core 120 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=200 ratetol=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'outvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=10-51, 200 kb/s, 60k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libfaac, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
Input Stream #0.0 frame size changed to 1920x1080, yuv420p
```

I tried all sorts of vcodec and the output is the same at best, also tried -sameq but no luck.

ffmpeg was installed via homebrew

Comment: Is it just this file or ffmpeg in general? Would you mind posting a similar file that you're having difficulty with somewhere public for us to test?

Comment: can we see file /usr.local/share/ffmpeg/libx264-medium.ffpreset - the parameter template you are using? Maybe it sets own video size or needs dimensions divisible by 64 pixels or so?

Comment: @ZaB The video size is fine, look at the output stream `#0.0`. The bit rate is too low, as you can see. Also, `ffpresets` shouldn't really be used anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things I'd like to point out:

- Upgrade your version of FFmpeg. It's terribly outdated. Run `brew update` and then `brew upgrade` to do so. FFmpeg 0.9 introduced a new way of specifying encoding presets, and the one you're currently using is just legacy.
- Don't ever use `sameq`. It *does not mean same quality*. It basically means, use the same mathematical options that were used in the input video, which in fact *drastically* reduces quality.

---

#### Where your problem is …

Let's get to the issue at hand. The output video has a bit rate of ~200 kBit/s, but your input has 14823 kBit/s. This is why it looks so bad. It now depends on what you want to do. If you just want to change the container to MP4, use `-vcodec copy` and be done with it.

If you want to change the frame size, use something like the following:

```
ffmpeg -i out_poem_big.mpg -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -s 1280x720 -c:a libfaac -b:a 128K outvideo.mp4
```

#### What does that mean?

- Most important aspect here is `-crf 22`, the Constant Rate Factor. Make it lower for better quality, make it larger for worse quality. See [this answer for a more thorough explanation](https://superuser.com/a/383946/48078) of what it means.

  If you need a constant output bit rate, replace `-crf 22` with `-b:v 1M`, for example. Note though that constant bit rate results in worse quality due to the way x264 handles it.
- `-c:v` is used instead of `-vcodec`. It means the same, but this is the default format and I'd prefer to stick to this. Also, we explicitly want `libx264` since all other encoders will likely reduce the quality you get for file size (like MPEG-4 Part II, `-c:v mpeg4`).
- `-preset slow` will use a slow variant of encoding with more bit-efficient optimization.
- I specified the audio codec and audio bitrate. Change it accordingly, depending on what you want to use.
- See these answer for more explanation about FFmpeg encoding:

  - [Resources To Use FFMPEG Effectively](https://superuser.com/questions/373018/resources-to-use-ffmpeg-effectively/373024#373024)
  - [Use DivX settings to encode to mp4 with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/380633/use-divx-settings-to-encode-to-mp4-with-ffmpeg/380757#380757)

Comment: Problem is that when I do brew ffmpeg upgrade I get ffmpeg already upgraded... Does it mean I am stuck with 0.6.3 as long as I use brew?

Comment: Did you do `brew update` before? If that doesn't work, uninstall it with `brew remove ffmpeg x264` and install again.

Comment: just did it and it keeps installing 0.6.3...?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. It's 0.10 now. I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: ok so it may not be the best solution, but I did this: `$ cd (tilda)brew --prefix(tilda)
$ git checkout fb01c6e /usr/local/Library/Formula/ffmpeg.rb
$ brew uninstall ffmpeg
$ brew install ffmpeg `
Had to `$ brew install x264` as well. There were some linking problems, but they got resolved by `$ sudo brew link ffmpeg`

Comment: Okay, well if it works for you :) Otherwise I'd recommend posting another question for that.